# Не удаётся вывести в ListViev список bluetooth-устройств

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

С Bluetooth работаю не так давно.
Вот код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BluetoothAdapter BluetoothAdapter;

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> pairedDeviceArrayList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDeviceAdapter;
    public static BluetoothSocket clientSocket;

    private OutputStream outStream;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static String address = "21:13:01:80:20";  //Вместо “00:00” Нужно нудет ввести MAC нашего bluetooth


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Switch ventil_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ventilator);
        Switch nagrev_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_nagrev);
        Switch pompa_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_pompa);
        Switch auto_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_auto);
        Button SearchSrart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartSearch);
        ListView Listarray = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Arraylist);

        ventil_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен вентилятор");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен вентилятор");
                }
            }
        });
        nagrev_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен нагреватель");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен нагреватель");
                }
            }
        });
        pompa_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включена помпа");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключена помпа");

                }
            }
        });
        auto_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    System.out.println("Включен автоматический режим");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Выключен автоматический режим");

                }
            }
        });

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
// С Bluetooth все в порядке.
        }

        SearchSrart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //если разрешения получены (функция ниже)
                if (permissionGranted()) {
                    //адаптер для управления блютузом
                    BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    if (bluetoothEnabled()) { //если блютуз включен (функция ниже)
                        findArduino(); //начать поиск устройства (функция ниже)
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private boolean permissionGranted () {
        //если оба разрешения получены, вернуть true
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void findArduino() {
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Arraylist);
        //получить список доступных устройств
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) { //если есть хоть одно устройство
            pairedDeviceArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //создать список
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice) {
                //добавляем в список все найденные устройства
                //формат: "уникальный адрес/имя"
                pairedDeviceArrayList.add(device.getAddress() + "/" + device.getName());
            }
        }

        //передаем список адаптеру, пригождается созданный ранее item_device.xml

        //на каждый элемент списка вешаем слушатель

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //через костыль получаем адрес
                String itemMAC = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().split("/", 2)[0];
                //получаем класс с информацией об устройстве
                BluetoothDevice connectDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(itemMAC);
                try {
                    //генерируем socket - поток, через который будут посылаться данные
                    Method m = connectDevice.getClass().getMethod(
                            "createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});

                    clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(connectDevice, 1);
                    clientSocket.connect();
                    if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                        //если соединение установлено, завершаем поиск
                        BluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //если разрешения получены (функция ниже)
        if(permissionGranted()) {
            //адаптер для управления блютузом
            BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if(bluetoothEnabled()) { //если блютуз включен (функция ниже)
                findArduino(); //начать поиск устройства (функция ниже)
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean bluetoothEnabled() {
//если блютуз включен, вернуть true, если нет, вежливо попросить пользователя его включить
        if(BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Я так понимаю, что проблема заключается в этих строчках, программа просто не может вывести данные об устроствах в ListViev:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //через костыль получаем адрес
                String itemMAC = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().split("/", 2)[0];
                //получаем класс с информацией об устройстве
                BluetoothDevice connectDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(itemMAC);
                try {
                    //генерируем socket - поток, через который будут посылаться данные
                    Method m = connectDevice.getClass().getMethod(
                            "createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});

                    clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(connectDevice, 1);
                    clientSocket.connect();
                    if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                        //если соединение установлено, завершаем поиск
                        BluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Подумал я об этом из-за того, что кнопка поиска устройств работает исправно (я так думаю).
Вот код кнопки поиска:

```
SearchSrart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //если разрешения получены (функция ниже)
                if (permissionGranted()) {
                    //адаптер для управления блютузом
                    BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    if (bluetoothEnabled()) { //если блютуз включен (функция ниже)
                        findArduino(); //начать поиск устройства (функция ниже)
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я у вас не увидел самого добавления в список данных, у вас комментарием написано:

```
//передаем список адаптеру, пригождается созданный ранее item_device.xml
```

но самого добавления я не увидел. Вот например у меня есть такая функция для заполнения списка:

```
private void setup() //функция для выбора устройства из списка доступных для подключения
    {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            listView = findViewById(R.id.pairlist);
            List<BluetoothDevice> data = new ArrayList<>(pairedDevices);

            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(data, getApplicationContext());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    device.getAddress();
                    myThreadConnectBTdevice = new ThreadConnectBTdevice(device);
                    myThreadConnectBTdevice.start();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

как можно увидеть, я работаю с ранее сопряженными устройствами и при выборе элемента списка произвожу подключение. В вашем случае вы формируете массив:

```
 if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) { //если есть хоть одно устройство
     pairedDeviceArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //создать список
      for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice) {
                //добавляем в список все найденные устройства
                //формат: "уникальный адрес/имя"
       pairedDeviceArrayList.add(device.getAddress() + "/" + device.getName());
    }
}
```

но ничего не передаете в список. Так же я бы вам советовал заменить тип данных который добавляется в массив, как можно увидеть из моей функции, я работаю сразу с устройством с которого можно вытащить и адрес и название и не хардкодить со строками :) Вот разметка которую я использую, может пригодится:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Для отображения данных в списке я использовал адаптер:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Context mContext;

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;
    }

    public ListAdapter(List<BluetoothDevice> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> dataSet = (ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>) data;
        this.mContext = context;


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
        Object object = getItem(position);
        BluetoothDevice dataModel = (BluetoothDevice) object;

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.name:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Name"+ Objects.requireNonNull(dataModel).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "Name " + dataModel.getName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();*/
                break;
        }
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        BluetoothDevice dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;
        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tvName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataModel).getName());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ! Но Android Studio ругается на строку ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(List, getApplicationContext()); Не понимаю, почемую

Comment: @Alex_8471, обновил ответ :)

Comment: при загрузке приложения, пишет, что внутренний элемент name должен быть либо ссылкой на ресурс, либо пустым. Пустым Студия его оставлять не даёт

Comment: а вы файл разметки для списка создали?

Comment: да как раз этот файл и оказывается пустым, и студия не хочет его таким запускать

Comment: что значит файл пустой? в нем есть текст какой-то? что вы подразумеваете под пустым файлом?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112213/discussion-between-alex-8471-and-andrew).